# Matlab: Dilation operator does not return the desired output

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

Suppose we want to enlarge black region in a binary image using morphological dilation operator in Matlab. The desired output must be as below, but the given code generate a different image!
[image]

```
bin = ones(10,10, 'uint8');
bin(3:8, 3:8) = 0;
bin([4 7], [4 7]) = 1;
nhood = [1 0 1; 
         0 0 0; 
         1 0 1];
dil = imdilate(bin, strel(nhood))
figure; 
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(255*bin, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(255*dil, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
```

Structuring element and original image are shown below:
[image]

Comment: if you want to enlarge the black region then erode image or first invert the image and then apply dilation and then invert again

Comment: You dilate the white regions, thus the white regions get bigger. Dilating the black regions is the oposite of dilating, eroding.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this video from edx DEV290x course: https://edx-video.net/MicrosoftDEV290x-V001100_DTH.mp4 @user8190410

Comment: Nope, I am not making a course to help you sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case your structuring element is inverted i.e. [255, 0, 255;0, 0, 0; 255, 0, 255] will be used when you make black region as foreground.

To get the result as shown in the video, you will have to use [0, 1, 0;1, 1, 1; 0, 1, 0] as a structuring element.

Note: Normally, in morphological operation you take **white region** as the foreground and use structuring element to modify the foreground. But in this [video](http://%20edx-video.net/MicrosoftDEV290x-V001100_DTH.mp4) he is using black region as foreground

```
bin = ones(10,10, 'uint8');
bin(3:8, 3:8) = 0;
bin([4 7], [4 7]) = 1;
nhood = [0 1 0; 
         1 1 1; 
         0 1 0];
erode = imerode(bin, strel(nhood));
dilate = imdilate(erode, strel(nhood));
figure; 
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(255*bin, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
subplot(2,2,2)
imshow(255*erode, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
title('after erosion')
subplot(2,2,3)
imshow(255*dilate, 'InitialMagnification', 'fit')
title('after dilation')
```

[image]

Comment: merci beaucoup for clarifying things up. @user8190410